# print string result in assembly

Tags: string, assembly, printing

```
; multi-segment executable file template.

data segment
   string db "THis is LuxUR in Summer."  
ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:
; set segment registers:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

  mov bx, offset string
  mov al, 0 ;      lower letters in word 
  mov dl,0  ; maximum letters

check:
mov cl, 41h ; from A-Z
mov ch, 5Ah   

mov ah, [bx]  
cmp ah, "."
je dot
cmp ah, " "
je empty 
jne letters

letters:   
cmp ah, cl 
je uppercase
inc cl
cmp cl, ch 
jne letters

mov cl, 61h     ; a-z
mov ch, 7Ah

lowercase: 
inc al
cmp dl,al 
jl maksimum

inc bx
jmp check

maksimum:
mov dl, al

inc bx
jmp check

uppercase:  
inc bx
jmp check    

empty:
mov al, 0
inc bx
jmp check

dot:
```

My program count lowercases in a word in al. and then puts in dl. (maximum lowercases) 
I have label which name is dot. there I have to put some instruction by which I can print my result:

> Summer is the word with the most lower cases 5

I try few instructions to do that but it doesnt work.

Comment: When you say it does not work, do you get *any* output? If so, what do you get?

Comment: my result is in dl register, and it is 5,

Comment: So you get the correct result, but you're simply asking how to print it? Are you allowed to use DOS interrupts?

Comment: i want to print that number (5) and the word Summer becouse that is the word with the most lowercases. I don't know which instruction to use, to print on the screen

Comment: yes that is my question, how to print 5 and Summer

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244624/print-integer-to-console-in-x86-assembly

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows, the easiest way is to use [DOS Interrupts](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html). Specifically, try [interrupt 09](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah09). This takes a string and outputs it to the standard output.

Comment: LEA DX, string
    MOV AH, 9
    INT 21H    
i try with this intterupt, but I get just the string printed on the screen ( all sentence with all words) I want to print just the result  Summer 5 letters

Comment: Sounds like you're printing the input, not the output. Remember you'll need to format the output before printing.

Comment: I dont know which interrupt to use, to print the 2 results, one the string Summer and the number of letters 5    the example code for it will be more usefull for me to understand

Comment: i really print the input, i dont understand how to print my output